# Passing data from one app to another app using onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass data from one app to another app using onActivityResult. Passing Data from 'A' to 'B' is OK. But when I try to return a string from B to A, data.getExtras() always returns null ...
Thanks in advance

My code:

In App A:

```
public void initAppB(Context context, String packageName, String codCli){
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (intent == null) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("codCli",codCli);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 123456);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String reg = "";
    if(requestCode == 123456) {
      if(resultCode == -1) {
        try{
            Bundle MBuddle = data.getExtras(); // >> ALWAYS RETURN NULL <<
            reg = MBuddle.getString("retorno");
        }catch(Exception e){
            log("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        CommitSale(reg);
      } else {
        // error
      }
    }
}
```

In App B:

```
....
//It's OK!! Receiving data!
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    codCli = extras.getString("codCli");
}

....

OnClickListener mBackListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String registro = "010000";
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.putExtra("retorno",registro);
        setResult(-1, intent); // --> Forcing returning code -1 (Ok)
        finish();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: in B:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("Date",dateSelected);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And, in A:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1) {
        Bundle mBundle = data.getExtras();
        String mMessage = mBundle.getString("Date");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try to understand "***what goes around that comes back around***" when you are trying to use `startActivityForResult()`

The problem here is that you are providing a `String` value in the `AppB`, like this

```
intent.putExtra("retorno",registro);
```

so what you should be reading is a String from the data like this... int AppA's `onActivityResult()`

```
data.getStringExtra("retorno");
```

because you are providing a String so you should expect a String in return,

what your code is trying to do is to read a `Bundle` in `onActivityResult()` like this...

`Bundle MBuddle = data.getExtras();`

which was never provided by the AppB,

If you would like you can have a look at one the example how to use `onActivityResult()` here [Github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/NoteListActivity.java)